# Basic set theory question on non disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint sets then what would $$(A\cap B)\cup(B^c\cap A) =?$$

Comment: Use Venn diagrams to solve these questions..

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The same thing it would be if they were disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

So, from the diagram $$B^c \cap A =\color{red}{\text{Red}} $$
$$A \cap B =\color{blue}{\text{Blue}} $$

So $$(A \cap B) \cup (B^c \cap A) =\color{blue}{\text{Blue}} \cup \color{red}{\text{Red}} =\color{orange}{\text{A}} $$

Answer (score 2):

It is $$(A\cap B)\cup(B^c\cap A) = (B\cup B^c) \cap A= A.$$

Note that this result always holds whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the distributive property of $\cap$ over $\cup$, that is

$$
(A \cap B) \cup ( A \cap C) = A \cap (B \cup C)
$$

Using it on the given problem
$$(A \cap B) \cup (B^c \cap A) = \\
(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) = \\
A \cap (B \cup B^c) = A
$$ 
Since $B \cup B^c =S$, the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

One of the distributive laws of set theory says that $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C) = A\cap (B\cup C)$. So in your case, $(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{c}) = A\cap (B\cup B^{c}) = A$.